# Understanding subtlety of move semantics involving struct

Tags: rust, move

I constructed this code example of seemingly inconsistent effect of what (is|is not) considered a move and hence (is|is not) allowed to compile in Rust.

```
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
    bazs: Vec<String>,
}


fn main() {
    let a: Foo = Foo {
        bar: "bar".to_string(),
        bazs: vec!["baz_1".to_string(), "bax_2".to_string()],
    };
    
    let b: String = a.bar;
    
    println!{"Who owns the String value, variable a or b? {b}"};
    
    
    // assigning a String (from a field of String type) to b IS NOT considered a move
    // assigning a String (from an element of field of Vec<String> type to IS considered a move
    // let c: String = a.bazs[0];
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da8bd7ae7b19ee2d388dbd9fe370f93d)

The example is based on the reading of the book of the Rust Programming language, in relation to thess sections where the move of Strings are discussed, but does not provide the sufficient reasoning for me to understand this constructed example yet:

- [Variables and Data Interacting with Move](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#variables-and-data-interacting-with-move)
- [Grouping Configuration Values](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html#grouping-configuration-values)

I hope to get some pointers on how to correctly understand this issue.

Comment: What is the "issue"? Right now you have made a number of statements (which may or may not be right), but you've left out asking an actual *question*. It is not clear exactly what your confusion with the example is, so please be precise.

Comment: The only thing I see that you've written that's wrong is that `let b = a.bar;` *is* considered a move.

Comment: @kmdreko Apologies for my ignorance and not making it clearer in the original example, but I was expecting to see a problem that BallpointBen filled in, that I would not be able to use the the struct in its entirety after a field of it is moved. Without knowing partial moves, I wouldn't be able to conceive the examples later given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust has partial moves. You can move both `a.bar` and `a.bazs` out of `a` separately. What you can't do is use `a` in its entirety after moving any of its (non-`Copy`) fields out. But the individual unmoved fields are still fair game. So this is fine:

```rust
let a: Foo = Foo {
    bar: "bar".to_string(),
    bazs: vec!["baz_1".to_string(), "bax_2".to_string()],
};

let b = a.bar;
let bazs = a.bazs;
```

While this is not:

```rust
let a: Foo = Foo {
    bar: "bar".to_string(),
    bazs: vec!["baz_1".to_string(), "bax_2".to_string()],
};

let b = a.bar;
let new_a = a;
```

You'll see

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `a`
partial move occurs because `a.bar` has type `std::string::String`,
which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```